# Links to Download older versions of Oracle Weblogic / OBI

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x, obiee

Not able to find below older versions on Oracle site for download.
I recall some of these were available till last year but now there's nothing.

Please help with the download links

```
-> Oracle Weblogic 10.3.3
-> Oracle Weblogic 10.3.6
-> Oracle Business Intelligence 10.1.3.4
-> Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, once Oracle software is out of support, it is removed from the download section on the OTN site so there's no way to download it any more, unless you have a valid support contract. In that case, contact Oracle and ask them to provide those files for you.